# computation of the inverse of large dimensional Kronecker sum

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are $p \times p$ positive definite matrices.

I want to compute
$X=\left[ (A\otimes I_p) + (I_p \otimes A)  \right] \left[ (B \otimes I_p) + (I_p \otimes B) \right]^{-1} (B^2 \otimes B^2)$.

When $p$ is small, it is straightforward to obtain $X$. However, when $p$ is large, since $X$ includes a huge matrix of dimension $p^2 \times p^2$, computation of $X$ is very time consuming or almost impossible.

I'm wondering if there are efficient ways to compute $X$ even for large $p$.

Answer (score 1):

By the spectral theorem we can write
$$
B = U D U^*
$$
for some $D>0$ and unitary $U$. Then
$$
B \otimes I + I \otimes B = (U \otimes U) (D \otimes I + I \otimes D) (U^* \otimes U^*).
$$
Thus To compute the inverse of $B \otimes  I + I \otimes B$ we need only compute
$$
(U \otimes U) (D \otimes I + I \otimes D)^{-1} (U^* \otimes U^*)
$$
and now the inverse is on a diagonal matrix (which we compute from $B$ only) and hence is much faster. We can also absorb the multiplication by $B^2 \otimes B^2$ into this computation as
$$
(B \otimes I + I \otimes B)^{-1}(B^2 \otimes B^2) = (U \otimes U) (D \otimes I + I \otimes D)^{-1}(D^2 \otimes D^2) (U^* \otimes U^*),
$$
which then implies the final multiplication can be reduced to multplication by a diagonal matrix.